# Java - Picture doesn't show until end of loop?

Tags: java, image, 2d, sprite

In Java, I have successfully displayed an image on the screen. Now I want to make it move by running it through a for loop. The for loop runs 10 times and sleeps for 1 second each time. Instead of moving the image every second as expected, I have to wait 10 seconds, then 10 images show up.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ImageDraw extends JComponent {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("player.png");

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                x+=10;
                y+=10;
                g2.drawImage(img1, x, y, this);
                repaint();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }   
        }   //end for

    }   //end paint

}   //end class
```

How would I make it so the image looks as if it's moving everytime it runs through the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Timer` for this, and get rid of the `Thread.sleep()`. You're running this code on the UI thread, and when you call `Thread.sleep()` you're putting the UI thread to sleep, which means no updating until the entire loop is complete.

Comment: Here's [a good tutorial for doing sprite animation like this](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/movingsprites/). Take a look specifically at the code for Board.java, which uses a Timer to perform an action every 5 milliseconds. Your code can be modified to work like this very easily.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other suggestions:

1. Never read the image in the painting method. Read the image when you construct the class or pass in the image with a setImage(...) method.
2. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method, not the paint() method.